# How return number of the word in text onclick or tap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ms-word, msdn

How can I return the number of the word in text onclick or tap?

I was thinking of using Find.HitHighlight Method (Word) - MSDN(or something similar) but I don't how. For now I can count words in the text I have and store them in collection but how can I now know which one was clicked or taped so it can return me number of that word in collection and highlight it.

Thanks a lot!

here is code for WordCount:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class WordCount : MonoBehaviour {
public Text textToCount;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Debug.Log(CountWords1(textToCount.text));
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public static int CountWords1(string s)
{
    MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(s, @"[\S]+");
    return collection.Count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is use a dictionary where each word is the key value.

```
public Dictionary<string, int> AnalyzeString(string str)
{
    Dictionary<string,int> contents = Dictionary<string,int>();
    string[] words = str.Split(' ');
    foreach(string word in words)
    {
        if(contents.ContainsKey(word))
        {
            contents[word]+=1;
        }
        else
        {
            contents.Add(word,1);
        }
    }
    return contents;
}
```

With this you can now see how many times the queried word is in the string.
just by doing

```
int numberOfTimes = 0;
if(contents.ContainsKey("yourDesiredWord"))
    numberOfTimes = contents["yourDesiredWord"];
```